# Friebase Firestore is not working. Doesn't even throw any errors

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to connect my Flutter app with Firebase. I followed their tutorial made changes and double checked app level and project level build.gradle files. Enabled Firestore and created a collection. I put the google_services.json file in the android/app directory. Everything is fine. It doesn't even throw an error. But the Firebase console doesn't show any updates. The following is the main.dart file I have written.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cake_of_the_day/login.dart';
import 'package:cake_of_the_day/catalogue.dart';
import 'package:cake_of_the_day/cart.dart';

Future<void> main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  CollectionReference cakes = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('cakes');

  cakes.add({'name':'asdasd', 'age':21}).then((value) => print("done")).catchError((error) {print(error);});

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Named Routes Demo',
      // Start the app with the "/" named route. In this case, the app starts
      // on the FirstScreen widget.
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
        '/': (context) => const LoginScreen(),
        // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
        '/catalogue': (context) => const Catalogue(),
        '/cart' : (context) => const Cart()
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my mobile's network form Wifi to Mobile Data. And it works now.